# What do I lose when I quit a multiplayer game in BF3?

Tags: battlefield-3

When I quit a multiplayer game in BF3, the game warns that "All progress will be lost". But I'm wondering if experience and unlocks will also be lost.

Comment: FWIW, I get that warning message even when I quit after the end of the round, even after all the medals and other awards have been posted. At that point the message is (I believe) simply incorrect: that's the one time I can be sure I _won't_ lose any progress. Which gives me the sneaking suspicion they may have built this dialog for the single player mission, then re-purposed it for the multiplayer without making it context-appropriate.

Comment: I always thought that the game updated your progress whenever it displayed the SAVING... message. This happens at the end of a round and possibly also at other times.

Comment: It sounds like no one is 100 per cent sure so if you quit except you might lose stuff or just hide & hope no one kills you before the game ends.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ONLY things that you lose for ending a game early are:

- Any points/kills/captures etc that you would have received while continuing to play.
- The ribbon for whatever gamemode you're playing (including the winners ribbon).
- Any end of round only ribbons like MVP or Ace Squad.
- It will always count as a loss on your record.

You won't lose any progress that you made during the match, including ribbons, medals or service stars.

Comment: Occasionally I have lost weapon unlocks when I leave early, though it's important to note that this is not every time and I'm fairly certain it's a bug and should not be happening.

Comment: @AlexanderKahoun Server crashes and client crashes behave differently to quitting early. If the server crashes you lose all of that game's progress, if you crash you sometimes lose a couple of minutes progress, are you sure you didn't crash those times?

Comment: I hadn't noticed if it was one or the other.  I'll have to pay more attention next time.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: thanks guys. good to know. NOTE. I thought I had lost unlocks.. but it turns out I had only unlocked them for the russian side !! I cant believe its now seperate unlocks for RU and US. !!

Comment: `You won't lose any progress that you made during the match, including ribbons, medals or service stars.` Not true, I got a Assault Service Star yesterday in game, quit the game in the time of rewards but before the loading of the new map. Result: Battlelog doesn't show a battlereport (played 3 maps there, ranked server), last server is not even close the last one and I don't have the Service Star and one rank less I should have (I guess they didn't save the last battle where I quit)

Comment: @WarrenFaith Either the server crashed or battlelog screwed up, it's an exception to the rule, and not the rule itself.

Comment: @MrSmooth well my experience with battlelog is: it screwed up. I see a lot of bugs around battlelog...

Comment: It will **not** count as a loss in your record. It merely counts as a quit

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, you get the points for captures and kills instantly during the game as those numbers pop-up. When the game ends, you get all of your bonuses for the win and ribbons and stuff. So, if you're not around for that, you won't get it.