# What XP do you lose when you exit a game mid play?

Tags: battlefield-3

I was wondering what you lose of the XP and progress you have made from the round you disconnect from.

Comment: You can probably find the answer here [What do I lose when I quit a multiplayer game in BF3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/what-do-i-lose-when-i-quit-a-multiplayer-game-in-bf3)